# Issue in expanding the width of the form in css

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a screenshot of the form (its in pc view) as shown below which I have to replicate in HTML/CSS.

[image]

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/228/embedded/result/) for the above screenshot.

**Problem Statement:**

**(1)** I am wondering what changes I need to do in the fiddle so that **I am able to expand the width of the form as marked by arrow in the screenshot above**.

I tried playing with the **margin and padding of the form class** as shown below but it didn't work.

Whenever **I increase the padding of the form, the input fields inside the form seems to go all over the place**.

```
.form {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24)
}
```

**(2)** Also, what changes I should make in the CSS, so that I can push the form (**as marked with orange sign in the form**) little bit towards the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried removing `max-width` and using `width instead`?
`max-width` sets a max width attribute on the form and I imagine there's some auto-scaling going on due to that.

Comment: reducing just the `padding` worked for me .. https://jsfiddle.net/takius/nc2djn5p/221/

Comment: I don't want to reduce the width of the form. Reducing the padding decreases the width of the form. **As soon as I increase the padding,  the input fields and text inside the form seems to go all over the place.**

Comment: What changes should I make in the form class so that on increasing the padding, `the width should increase` ?

Comment: in the fiddle : changing the padding will not change the width, `box-sizing: border-box` will not change the width when you change the padding , `box-sizing: content-box` will change the width when you change the padding, pick one and add it to the `.form`

Comment: Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/224/embedded/result/) It worked for me. I am wondering what changes I need to do so that I am able to move `Hello World`
and `000X, Abcd to Pqrst` lines to the top most extreme left of the form.

Comment: At this moment, these lines are the center of the form but I want to move it at the top-most extreme left.

Comment: No worries. I am able to figure out. Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/226/embedded/result/)

Comment: add `margin-top:30px` to the `.login-page` ( not `.form` ) for the space on top

Comment: @Taki In order to make the question clear, I have updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/227/embedded/result/). The form should be present inside the background-color: #BFBFBF; At this moment, it is on the border.

Comment: add `padding-top: 25px;` to `.login-page`

Comment: @Taki Thanks, it worked. I am wondering why margin-top: 25px doesn't work ?

Comment: google : margin collapsing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170043/discussion-between-user5447339-and-taki).

Answer (score 1):

Give the text input fields a width of 100% then you can use the paddings to control the size of the form elements.

```
.form {
background: #FFFFFF;
max-width: 360px;
margin: 150px auto 100px auto;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24)
}

input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note that I've modified the `.form` styles a little bit.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I have one more question if you check the screen-shot above. I am wondering what I have to change in the fiddle so that I can give some about `some amount of space to the form from the top`.

Comment: I have marked the **arrow orange sign** in the screenshot so that its easy to understand.

Comment: You're welcome. And to do that use `margin-top`   , this will create space outside the form.

Comment: I've updated the margins property in the answer I posted.

Comment: The form should be present inside the `background-color: #BFBFBF;` At this moment, it is on the border.

Comment: Did you understand my question ?

Comment: Add a display property to the form and modify the margin property like so: `display: block; margin: 150px auto 100px auto; `.  You can also add the position property for the form should in case the above didn't work out: `position: relative`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170009/discussion-between-user5447339-and-john-zenith).